# set css value with variable and unity

Tags: css

I hope to change css value with an unity, like text-spacing,here is my code

```
    $("#spacing #t_number").keyup(function(){
    var t_number=$("#spacing #t_number").val();
    $("#spacing #text_content").css("letter-spacing", "NEW_VALUE");
});
```

Now the NEW_VALUE Is waiting for something like "3em" which means a value from t_number and an unity "em", but i dont know how to combine these two parts. I've tried many combination and nothing works. Please help me out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="user" />
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#user").keyup(function(){
        var t_number=$("#user").val();
        $("#text").css("letter-spacing", t_number+'em');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8FAV/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var t_number = '3em';
$("#spacing #text_content").css("letter-spacing", t_number);
```

Comment: hi, you're right. but the number 3 is a value typed by the user, and the problem is how could I put 3 and "em" together.

Comment: You need to concatenate the values. Something like this: `t_number+'em'`.

Comment: @webrocker Make sure you don't have set !important on letter-spacing in #spacing #text_content. Otherwise, this will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/g8FAV/1/ Also, make sure you have included jQuery library, that the rest of your code doesn't have syntax errors that will cause code to stop working and check if you have $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); part of code.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović great, it works now. I mismatched button id and content id. Thank you !!! Can you put your answer as a normal answer that I can vote for it ?